# Clicking on non-text area inside checkbox fails to check item using WPF framework

Tags: wpf, xaml, checkbox, data-binding, combobox

I have a combobox control containing a list of checkboxes. The structure is as followed:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbxRH" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="500.5,80,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="126" IsEditable="True" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" StaysOpenOnEdit="True" TextBoxBase.TextChanged="cbxRH_TextChanged" Grid.Column="2">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
          <CheckBox x:Name="chkRH" IsChecked="{Binding checkStatus}" CommandParameter="{Binding index}" Checked="chk_Checked"  Unchecked="chk_Unchecked">
             <CheckBox.Content>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LO_Name_short}"/>
             </CheckBox.Content>
          </CheckBox>
       </DataTemplate>
     </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Now when I click the checkbox or the item text, I can select the item. But Only when I click the background(non-text area), nothing is selected and `MyProject.BindClass` appears in the textbox of combobox. `MyProject` is the project name and `BindClass` is the class whose properties are bund to the event shown above.

Is there a way that makes it possible that clicking on non-text area also enables to select items?

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49126802/1506454) in particular should help. add Background to TextBlock to see the difference. At the moment clicks go to ComboBoxItems, to to ChechBox

Comment: @ASh Thank you very much for your help. I didn't find right key word to search for solutions. Your answer helps a lot.

Comment: @ASh I've solved the problem and set the property. But Now I have a new one. When I click the border of the combobox or the joint line of two combobox items, the same situation happens. Do you have an advice?